# How to add a widget in .phtml template file using it's id?

Tags: magento2.4, phtml

I have a widget created from admin panel (Image below)

[image]

I want to add this widget in My Account (dashboard) page (Image below)

[image]

How do I do that. I have extended Magento_Customer module and added my custom template file into it (Image below)

[image]

The code in customer_account_index is

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
            <action method="setPageTitle">
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">My Account</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info" name="customer_account_dashboard_info"
                   as="info" template="Magento_Customer::account/dashboard/info.phtml" cacheable="false">
                <container name="customer.account.dashboard.info.blocks" as="additional_blocks"/>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Address" name="customer_account_dashboard_address"
                   as="address" template="Magento_Customer::account/dashboard/address.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
            <block name="customer_account_image_slider" template="Magento_Customer::imageSlider.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

I added

```
<block name="customer_account_image_slider" template="Magento_Customer::imageSlider.phtml"/>
```

Now, in imageSlider.phtml file, How do I get the widget that I created through admin panel and show it also, how can I style that widget that I created in admin panel?

Comment: You want to get value of that widget in FE template file?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to get that widget by id in the FE template file. But, I found that I could use 

```
 <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="imageSlider">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">image-slider-widget-container</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
```

this code to show a widget through a block. So, create a block in admin and add widget into it and use this code in ur xml file using the block identifier from admin